# How can I create a trigger that before updating a column in a table saves the entire old row into a new table?

Tags: mysql, laravel, triggers, sql-update

I have the `team_members` table, with the following structure, where only `project_request_id` gets updated. I created `log_team_members` with the same data structure, so whenever I update team_members I lose the old data, which I need for reads, that's why I was thinking of creating a `trigger` that `before updating team_members project_request_id`, it saves the entire `old row` to this table.

Can you help me to build this trigger from a Latavel migration?

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('team_members', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('picture');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('phone_number');
        $table->text('background_information')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('project_request_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('project_request_id')->references('id')->on('project_requests')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('team_members', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('picture');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('phone_number');
        $table->text('background_information')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('project_request_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('project_request_id')->references('id')->on('project_requests')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

And this where the team_members update happens:

```
public function createProjectTeam(Request $request){
            try {
                $projectRequest = 
ProjectRequest::create(['project_title' => $request->projectTitle, 
'client_id' => $request->projectClientId]);

                TeamMember::whereIn('email', $request->projectTeamEmails)
                ->update([
                    'project_request_id' => $projectRequest->id 
                ]);

                $projectTeam = TeamMember::where('project_request_id', $projectRequest->id)->get();

            return response()->json( [
                'success'=> true,
                'projectRequest' => $projectRequest,
                'projectTeam' => $projectTeam,
            ]);

            } catch(\Exception $e){
                return ['success' => false, 'message' => 'project team creation failed'];
            }

        }
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events

Comment: so does the `updating` event correspond to before update?

Comment: Yes, `-ing` is before and `-ed` is after

Comment: In this case what would `$event->teamMember` in my Listener contain at this time, if you know what I mean? Can I access all the properties of the TeamMember model, like `$event->teamMember->name`  and so on so I can save them in my new table?

Comment: or only the values coming from the update request, that is,  `email` and `project_request_id`?

Comment: Why don't you try it out? Best way to know for sure. You might even be able to answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

```php
// use DB; 
$data = UpdateModelName::find(1);
$copy = $data->replicate()->toArray();
// store data in new table
$newTable = new NewTableModel;
$newTable->insert($copy);
```